# Probability of one claim from two independent poissons

Tags: probability

A family buys two insurance policies from the same insurance company. The number of claims on each policy is a Poisson variable with mean $0.25$. Claims under the two policies are independent. Find the probability exactly one policy has exactly one claim.

Am I correct in going about it like this:
$$P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)=2P(X=1,Y=0)$$ Which is equal to $$2P(X=1)P(Y=0)\text{ due to independence}$$So we have $$2e^{-.25}(.25)\cdot{e^{-.25}}=.303$$ Or should I be doing just $P(X=1)P(Y=0)$ since it says exactly one policy has exactly one claim?

Comment: Your first way is correct.

Comment: The first way looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or should I be doing just $P(X=1)P(Y=0)$ since it says exactly one policy has exactly one claim?

Sure, it says exactly one, however, *which* one is not sepecified.

Thus the first calculation is correct.   That is the probability for *either one* from the two policies having exactly one claim and *whichever is the other* having exactly zero.

Due to being i.i.d. random variables that is: $2\,\mathsf P(X=1)\,\mathsf P(X=0) \\~=~ 2\cdot(0.25)^1\mathsf e^{-0.25}\cdot(0.25)^0\mathsf e^{-0.25} \\~=~ \tfrac 12 \mathsf e^{-1/2}$

As you had it.  $\checkmark$